# kubernetes how to set the maximum size of the log file?

Tags: logging, docker, rotation, kubernetes, coreos

How to set the maximum size of the log file? Or enable log rotation. 
In the documentation I have not found anything about this.

Or it is necessary to write a script for this?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this

Comment: I have not found a good way. I wrote a script which gets all namespaces and then all pods in the system. Then I get the information on what host and container id. With this data the script does a `SSH $user@$node "sudo truncate -s 0 /var/lib/Docker/containers/$id/$id-json.log"`
But I have not tested it fully

Comment: Maximum log size for what? What environment are you running on? Log rotation should be setup if you're using any of the default deployments (via  [salt](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/295f1786fbadb1d2e6d5ea1453ec905c48be54a9/cluster/saltbase/salt/logrotate))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think kubernetes provides log rotation feature now. You can put logrotate configuration in your host machine. Something like this one:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
  rotate 7
  daily
  size=10M
  compress
  missingok
  delaycompress
  copytruncate
}
```